# SQL Server Data Lost on User DB's

Tags: sql-server-2008, data-loss

I'm facing a very complex situation with my software databases on a specific server. This is the second time this problem happend on this server. 
Basically while user where working on the system, with no apparently reason, all the data from three user databases where lost.

The 3 databases where put on a previuos state from 1.5 month ago where all the databases changes made to this databases are lost, yes LOST! I had to restore a backup for all the databases but the data from passed two dates after the last backup where lost. The first time this happend, was with SQL Server Express 2008. Now happends on SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard.

I suspect a hardware / OS (Hard drive, RAM, etc) problem with the server itself, but no other data where lost (data files, etc) on SQL Server data.

The only lead i have to discover what happend is the Sql Server LOG, where i see some strange entrys:

[image]

```
1) All the log previous to 06/08/2015 11:55 (the exact moment where the problem apear) is lost.
2) An error during decryption, which don't know what it means.
3) A "Recovery complete" message
4) After that I see on the log constant message from CHECKDB over my users database (a lot of them) wich no one execute.
```

Does anyone have any idea of what could be hapenning here?

Is this a Hardware issue like I suspect?

Thanks!

Comment: can you expand on what you mean by "all the data from the three user databases were lost"? Are you saying all the tables are empty/gone?  Please be more specific about exactly what happened and when.

Comment: Tables that has 100 records, have now only one or two. Tables created recently are missing. Also Views. Autonumeric fields are back to lower values, so no delete where done. Looking at the event log from the server i found that a user manually stop SQL Server service and start it again 20 minutes after. Still don't know what he did in the meedle.

Comment: That sounds like someone restored a backup.  run `select top 100 * from msdb..restorehistory order by restore_date desc` and see if anything makes sense.